# Component not visible after all/most of its parents are disabled

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I have multiple components one nested into another. Like one `<s:Group />` is child of other `<s:Group />` which is child of another `<s:Group />` and so on. The problem is that different components gets disabled depending on different conditions. It might happen that all components are disabled at once, due to which the innermost component loses its visibility.
I am posting a sample code here depicting my situation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" >
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Group horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" >
        <s:Group enabled="false">
            <s:Group enabled="false">
                <s:Group enabled="false" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
                    <mx:Canvas disabledOverlayAlpha="1" width="{tlGroup.width}" height="{tlGroup.height}">
                        <s:TileGroup id="tlGroup" enabled="false" >

                            <mx:CheckBox selected="true" enabled="true"/>
                            <mx:CheckBox enabled="true" />
                        </s:TileGroup>
                    </mx:Canvas>
                </s:Group>
            </s:Group>
        </s:Group>
    </s:Group>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Further I cannot use `disabledAlpha=""` as I am using Halo theme in additional compiler arguments(`-theme=${flexlib}/themes/Halo/halo.swc`).

Comment: Do you know that if you disable the outermost element, all the inner elements will be disabled as well? I did not understand your question.

Comment: I'm also unsure what you're asking.  Are you trying to hide the `TileGroup` when it's disabled?  Are you looking for help with the different conditions that disable different `Groups`?  Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good case for using [Flex states](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63611-7ff1.html).

Add to your MXML file the code:

```
   <s:states>
            <s:State name="my_state_1" />
            <s:State name="my_state_2" />
   </s:states>
```

And then add to your groups and/or elements `includeIn="my_state_1"` and `enabled.my_state_2="true"` etc.

Comment: If my `currentState` is `my_state_1` and I disabled some components dynamically using AS code and then I set `currentState` to `my_state_2` and then switch back to `my_state_1` after some user interaction. Will that changes remain which I made earlier or the `State` starts from its initial definition?

Comment: Why don't you try it out yourself?

Comment: yup! my fault. I'm sorry.